# Issue in report record is not getting display for one user and showing other user with same profile

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom

I have one report when i am login with the one user its display the records in report but for other user records are not getting displayed.
Both User have same profile and role.Please suggest which permission or what is missing.

Comment: Check for the OWD of the object, if its private then the record owner can see the record. Make sure the other user can see the record from the object home.

Comment: Its Controlled by Parents

Comment: Was the other user able to see the record from record home page?

Comment: both can see the records but when i am running report then one cannot see .Is there anything depened on role

Comment: Does the report settings still have my records as one of the criteria?